# Eclipse - adding -noverifycannot to jvm arguments

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse and setting the below arguments in JVM arguments tab.

> -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/Users/test/team/client_jaas.conf

When, I run the program, I am getting the below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File
>   /Users/test/team/client_jaas.conf-noverifycannot be read.

I dont know why am i getting this error even the file exist at the specified location.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_acs_config_location.html) help?

Comment: It might be a typo - but is this correct, it doesnt look like it `/Users/test/team/client_jaas.conf-noverify`, e.g. theres no space between conf and `-noverify`

Comment: This is how eclipse complain.